# Converting a string formatted YYYYMMDDHHMMSS into a JavaScript Date object

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

I have a string with a date in it formatted like so: YYYYMMDDHHMMSS. I was wondering how I would convert it into a JavaScript Date object with JavaScript.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this for a wacky way to do it:

```
var date = new Date(myStr.replace(
    /^(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)$/,
    '$4:$5:$6 $2/$3/$1'
));
```

Zero external libraries, one line of code ;-)

---

**Explanation of the original method :**

```
// EDIT: this doesn't work! see below.
var date = Date.apply(
    null,
    myStr.match(/^(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)$/).slice(1)
);
```

The `match()` function (after it has been `slice()`d to contain just the right) will return an array containing year, month, day, hour, minute, and seconds. This just happens to be the exact right order for the Date constructor. `Function.apply` is a way to call a function with the arguments in an array, so I used `Date.apply(<that array>)`.

for example:

```
var foo = function(a, b, c) { };

// the following two snippets are functionally equivalent
foo('A', 'B', 'C')

var arr = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
foo.apply(null, arr);
```

I've just now realised that this function doesn't actually work, since javascript months are zero-indexed. You could still do it in a similar method, but there'd be an intermediate step, subtracting one from the array before passing it to the constructor. I've left it here, since it was asked about in the comments.

The other option works as expected however.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on in the first case? What is 'apply' doing?

Comment: This is how I'd do it.  Unless you need a bunch of other date processing, these external libs are overkill.

Comment: the first version shouldn't work: according to ECMA-262, 3rd edition, section 15.9.2, calling `Date()` as a function (ie without `new`) always returns a string representation of the **current time**; quote: "any arguments supplied are accepted but are completely ignored"

Comment: the arguments to `apply()` would also be wrong even if it worked: correct usage would be `Date.apply(null, myStr.match(/.../).slice(1))`

Comment: @Christoph: yep, you're right. Even then, there were other problems with that method. In my (obviously brief) testing, `Date.apply` did work as I'd hoped though.

Comment: Thank you, you've also inspired me to dive a bit deeper into regexp since you make it look so easy ;).

Comment: Where does myStr come from? How can we initialize it?

Comment: I'm getting an error for `myStr`, I must be missing something?

Comment: such a sexy solution

Comment: _“Note: Parsing of date strings with the `Date` constructor (and `Date.parse`, which works the same way) is **strongly discouraged** due to browser differences and inconsistencies.”_ — From the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#parameters). The correct solution will look something like `const { year, month, day, hour, minute, second } = theDateString.match(/(?<year>\d{4})(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2})(?<hour>\d{2})(?<minute>\d{2})(?<second>\d{2})/).groups, result = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, second);`.

Answer (score 9):

Primitive version:

```
new Date(foo.slice(0, 4), foo.slice(4, 6) - 1, foo.slice(6, 8),
    foo.slice(8, 10), foo.slice(10, 12), foo.slice(12, 14))
```

An explicit  conversion of the strings to numbers is unnecessary: the `Date()` function will do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

I find [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) the best library for anything that has to do with converting, parsing and using dates in JavaScript. If you need that kind of conversions more often you should really consider using it in your application:

```
Date.parseExact("20091202051200", "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery, jQuery.ui.datepicker has a utility [function](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate).

Answer (score 0):

Date functions from this library can help: http://javascripttoolbox.com/lib/date/ , it's free and very simple to use.

If you want to do it yourself, I would suggest looking up the javascript regular expressions, as I guess that is the way to achieve this best

Answer (score 0):

There is no time zone information in your string.
It most likely is GMT, so that should be accounted for
when you make the Date. You can easily do the conversion with simple javascript methods.

```
Date.Brit= (function(){
    return Date.parse('2/6/2009')> Date.parse('6/2/2009');
})()


var s= "20091202093000"
var D= s.match(/(\d{2})/g);
if(Date.Brit){
    D.splice(2, 2, D[3],D[2]);
}
var day= new Date(Date.parse(D[2]+'/'+D[3]+'/'+
D[0]+D[1]+' '+D.splice(4).join(':')+' GMT'));

day.toUTCString()+'\n'+day


/*  returned value: (String)
Wed, 02 Dec 2009 09:30:00 GMT
Wed Dec 02 2009 04:30:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
*/
```