# Javascript: convert date string to date object correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string date for example '20200321082245'. I am trying to convert it by pure Javaccript code to a date object by spliting it and creating an date object
for example:

**'20200321082245' --> 2020-03-21 08:22:45**

**'202003210.2245'** --> This case with a dot must be excluded. I must return a null date object

How can I convert it correctly ? Since the syncDate could contain a dot also for example a double number also not integer.

**My Code:**

```
        function convertDate(syncDate){
            var date = null;
            if(syncDate){
            try {
                if (!isNaN(syncDate)) {
                        var d = syncDate.toString().match(/.{1,2}/g)
                        var len = d.length;
                        var dateString = '';
                        switch(len){
                            case 2:
                                dateString = d[0]+d[1];
                            case 3:
                                dateString = d[0]+d[1] +'-'+d[2]
                            case 4:
                                dateString = d[0]+d[1] +'-'+d[2]+'-'+d[3]
                            case 5:
                                dateString = d[0]+d[1] +'-'+d[2]+'-'+ d[3]+' '+d[4]
                            case 6:
                                dateString = d[0]+d[1] +'-'+d[2]+'-'+d[3]+' '+d[4]+':'+d[5];
                            case 7:
                                dateString = d[0]+d[1] +'-'+d[2]+'-'+d[3]+' '+d[4]+':'+d[5]+':'+d[6];
                        }
                      if(dateString)
                         date = new Date(dateString);
                    }
                } catch (e) {}
            }

            return date;
         }
```

Comment: You're already using a regular expression. Use one that matches all of the date parts, convert the parts to actual numbers and construct the date with them.

Comment: @Andreas: something like /^\d+$/.test(syncDate). Sorry but I am not well  familiar with regex.

Comment: Constructing the date like I am doing in the switch parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var value = '20200321082245';
var dateRx = /(^\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)?(\d\d)?(\d\d)?/;
if (dateRx.test(value)) {
    return new Date(value.replace(dateRx, '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6'));
}
return null;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, What about this one '20200321082'.replace(/(^\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/, '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6') -->I am getting as result the following '20200321082'

Comment: I am not getting a result for var value = '2020032108'; since new Date('2020-03-21 08:') is an date object

Comment: Therefore I am building the string in the switch part

Comment: You did not provide such an example in your question.
Write your question more clearly and you'll get a right answer

Comment: Anyway, you can achieve what you want by making last three groups optional. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the string contains a *.* by using the *includes* property.

```
if(string.includes('.')){
    return null;
}
```

About converting it into a date object, there are several ways to achieve this.
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833892/converting-a-string-formatted-yyyymmddhhmmss-into-a-javascript-date-object)