# How to convert YYYYMMDDHHMMSS to UTC using offset

Tags: javascript, node.js, date-formatting, date-conversion

I am getting date in object having localTimeStamp and UTC offset as below.

```
obj = {
 "localTimeStamp": 20200908232201 //YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
 "utcTimeOffset" : "+0630"
}
```

How to convert this into

Local Date time - format DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS

UTC Date time - format DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS

I have tried below solution, But how to convert in UTC.

```
"20200908232201".replace(/^(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)$/,'$2-$3-$1 $4:$5:$6');
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother and use MomentJS, which has it all sorted out for you already. Date manipulation, formatting, time zones , you name it

Comment: @JeremyThille, Everything avialable in universe, so why this forum exists?

Comment: @NRaj is `localTimeStamp` just a regular Unix timestamp?

Comment: @JanakiRajeshDuvvuri, Its a date format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to use any library then you can try the below approach:

You already have the date in the required format - `(DD-MM-YYY HH:MM:SS)`.

```
let utcTimeOffset = '+0630';

  var d = new Date(
  '20200908232201'.replace(
    /^(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)$/,
    '$2-$3-$1 $4:$5:$6'
  ) + utcTimeOffset
);
```

Then use the [`UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) for the above date to convert the date to UTC:

```
var utcDate = new Date(
  Date.UTC(
    d.getUTCFullYear(),
    d.getUTCMonth(),
    d.getUTCDate(),
    d.getUTCHours(),
    d.getUTCMinutes(),
    d.getUTCSeconds()
  )
);
```

Finally use the below formatting to print the date in required fromat -

```
var MyDateString =
  ('0' + utcDate.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) +
  '-' +
  ('0' + (utcDate.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
  '-' +
  utcDate.getUTCFullYear() +
  ' ' +
  ('0' + utcDate.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) +
  '-' +
  ('0' + utcDate.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) +
  '-' +
  ('0' + utcDate.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);

console.log(MyDateString); //08-09-2020 16-52-01
```

```js
let utcTimeOffset = '+0630';

var d = new Date(
  '20200908232201'.replace(
    /^(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)$/,
    '$2-$3-$1 $4:$5:$6'
  ) + utcTimeOffset
);

var utcDate = new Date(
  Date.UTC(
    d.getUTCFullYear(),
    d.getUTCMonth(),
    d.getUTCDate(),
    d.getUTCHours(),
    d.getUTCMinutes(),
    d.getUTCSeconds()
  )
);


var MyDateString =
  ('0' + utcDate.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) +
  '-' +
  ('0' + (utcDate.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
  '-' +
  utcDate.getUTCFullYear() +
  ' ' +
  ('0' + utcDate.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) +
  '-' +
  ('0' + utcDate.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) +
  '-' +
  ('0' + utcDate.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);

console.log(MyDateString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) library, this is really a successor to moment.js and has a lot of powerful date handling functionality.

In particular we can use the [DateTime.fromFormat](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#static-method-fromFormat) function to parse the date supplied.

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const obj = {
     "localTimeStamp": 20200908232201, //YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
     "utcTimeOffset" : "+0630"
}

const dt = DateTime.fromFormat(obj.localTimeStamp + obj.utcTimeOffset, "yyyyMMddHHmmssZZZ", { setZone: true } );
console.log("Local time:", dt.toISO())
console.log("UTC Time:", dt.toUTC())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.25.0/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-OyrI249ZRX2hY/1CAD+edQR90flhuXqYqjNYFJAiflsKsMxpUYg5kbDDAVA8Vp0HMlPG/aAl1tFASi1h4eRoQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  localTimeStamp: 20200908232201,
  utcTimeOffset : "+0630"
};

const date = new Date((new Date(obj.localTimeStamp)).toUTCString() + obj.utcTimeOffset);

console.log(date.toUTCString());
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: obj.localTimeStamp is not miliseconds,  its date in format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the localTimeStamp (I got this agreeable idea from Christoph's answer [Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833892/converting-a-string-formatted-yyyymmddhhmmss-into-a-javascript-date-object))

```js
const obj = {
    "localTimeStamp": "20200908232201",
    "utcTimeOffset": "+0630"
};
let localTimeStamp = obj.localTimeStamp;
let utcTimeOffset = obj.utcTimeOffset;
let formattedDate = new Date(localTimeStamp.slice(0, 4), localTimeStamp.slice(4, 6) - 1, localTimeStamp.slice(6, 8), localTimeStamp.slice(8, 10), localTimeStamp.slice(10, 12), localTimeStamp.slice(12, 14));
let formattedDateToLocal = new Date(formattedDate + utcTimeOffset);
let formattedDateToUTC = new Date(formattedDate.toUTCString() + utcTimeOffset);
   
console.log(`UTC : ${formattedDateToUTC.getDate()}-${formattedDateToUTC.getMonth()}-${formattedDateToUTC.getFullYear()} ${formattedDateToUTC.getHours()}:${formattedDateToUTC.getMinutes()}:${formattedDateToUTC.getSeconds()}`)
console.log(`Local : ${formattedDateToLocal.getDate()}-${formattedDateToLocal.getMonth()}-${formattedDateToLocal.getFullYear()} ${formattedDateToLocal.getHours()}:${formattedDateToLocal.getMinutes()}:${formattedDateToLocal.getSeconds()}`)
```